# Month and Year options parameter in SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2012

--Hello,

I would like to know if there is a way that the user can have a choice
to select the date range in month (mm/dd/yyyy) or in year (yyyy)...(e.g. using drop down list)

For example......

If the user select "DateByMonth" from drop down list in the Preview mode, then the user can enter the date range in month.

**Start Date:** 1/1/2014    **End Date:** 1/1/2016

The output should be something like this.

```
    1/2014  | 2/2014 | 3/2014 | .... | 10/2015 | .... | 1/2016|
qty   1         6        9                3               6
rev   2         3        2                12              0
```

If the user select "DateByYear" from drop down list in the Preview mode, then the user can enter the date range in year.

**Start Date:** 2014    **End Date:** 2016

The output should be something like this.

```
    2014 | 2015 | 2016
qty 16     3      6
rev 7      12     0
```

You might have a better solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to make report with parameter for choose display type **(Daily,weekly,monthly,yearly or quarter)**

and I use Expression in DataSet for make dynamic Query.

This's some Expression in my DataSet

```
="DECLARE @paramSdate AS DATE = @Strdate "&
"DECLARE @paramNdate AS DATE = @endDate "&
Switch(
Parameters!displayType.Value = "D",
    .... Generate Daily into temp table .....
Parameters!displayType.Value = "W" ,
    .... Generate weekly into temp table ......
Parameters!displayType.Value = "M" ,
    .... Generate monthly into temp table ......
Parameters!displayType.Value = "Y",
    .... Generate yearly into temp table ......
Parameters!displayType.Value = "Q",
    .... Generate quarter into temp table .......
)
```

I use displayType parameter for determine what query use.

It's just Guide not complete code.

**UPDATE 1**

Ok.. Thank you for script create table and data

It's look like you expect result must use `UNPIVOT`

I make sample 2 Query monthly and yearly

**Monthly**

```
DECLARE @paramSdate AS DATE = CAST('2015-02-01' AS DATE)
DECLARE @paramNdate AS DATE = CAST('2015-09-30' AS DATE)
DECLARE @temp AS DATE = @paramSDate

CREATE TABLE #tmp (label VARCHAR(10),m INT,yy INT)
 -- Monthly
WHILE @temp < @paramNdate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmp
        SELECT FORMAT(@temp,'MM/yyyy'),MONTH(@temp),YEAR(@temp)
    SET @temp = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@temp)
END

;WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT upv.col
        ,upv.yy
        ,upv.m
        ,upv.value
    FROM (
        SELECT t.label
            ,t.m
            ,t.yy
            ,ISNULL(val.Qty,0) AS [Qty]
            ,ISNULL(val.Rev,0) AS [Rev]
        FROM #tmp t
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT CAST(Rev AS INT) AS [Rev]
                ,CAST(Qty AS INT) AS [Qty]
                ,MONTH(DateDA) AS [mm]
                ,YEAR(DateDA) AS [yyy]
            FROM Main_Table m with(nolock)
            WHERE m.DateDA BETWEEN  CAST('2/13/2015' AS DATE) AND  CAST('9/23/2015' AS DATE)
        ) val ON val.mm = t.m AND val.yyy = t.yy
    ) src
    UNPIVOT
    (
        value
        FOR col IN ([Rev],[Qty])
    ) upv
)

SELECT CTE.col
    ,CAST(CTE.m AS varchar(10)) + '/' + CAST(CTE.yy AS varchar(10)) AS [label]
    ,CTE.value
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CTE.yy,CTE.m

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Explain : First, I create temporary table for generate date range record Then use `UNPIVOT`  to get result like this image below

[image: unpivotResult]

and Finally, I use grouping in SSRS like this

[image: design_layout]

And you will get this result when Run

[image: Result]

and for Yearly I make query are same monthly

**Yearly**

```
DECLARE @paramSdate AS DATE = CAST('2015-02-01' AS DATE)
DECLARE @paramNdate AS DATE = CAST('2017-09-30' AS DATE)
DECLARE @temp AS DATE = @paramSDate

CREATE TABLE #tmp (yy INT)
 -- Yearly
WHILE YEAR(@temp) <= YEAR(@paramNdate)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmp
        SELECT YEAR(@temp)
    SET @temp = DATEADD(YEAR,1,@temp)
END

;WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT upv.col
        ,upv.value
        ,upv.yy
    FROM (
        SELECT t.yy
            ,ISNULL(val.Qty,0) AS [Qty]
            ,ISNULL(val.Rev,0) AS [Rev]
        FROM #tmp t
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT CAST(Rev AS INT) AS [Rev]
                ,CAST(Qty AS INT) AS [Qty]
                ,YEAR(DateDA) AS [yy]
            FROM Main_Table m with(nolock)
            WHERE m.DateDA BETWEEN  CAST('2/13/2015' AS DATE) AND  CAST('9/23/2017' AS DATE)
        ) val ON val.yy = t.yy
    ) src
    UNPIVOT
    (
        value
        FOR col IN ([Rev],[Qty])
    ) upv
)


SELECT CTE.col
    ,CTE.yy AS [label]
    ,CTE.value
FROM CTE 

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Then if you want to use parameter for user select display type you can use query like this

```
DECLARE @displayType NVARCHAR(100) = @param

IF @displayType = 'DateByMonth' 
BEGIN
    ..... Code for Monthly ......
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    ..... Code for Yearly ......
END
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Hi @hanom. Thanks for reply. I need  a drop down list option so  the user can select the date like Year or Month. In the run time there will be three parameters. _1) select date format -- DateByMonth or DateByYear 2) StartDate 3) EndDate._ 
Here is the table for data type **create table Dates (DateType varchar(15))
insert into Dates values ('DateByMonth'), ('DateByYear')**

Comment: and the main table  is **create table Main_Table (Item int,Rev varchar(10),Qty int,DateD int,DateDA varchar(20))
insert into Main_Table values (1, 1, 5995, 2015, '9/23/2015'), (2, 3, 5995, 2015, '7/30/2015'),
(3, 1, 5995, 2015, '5/19/2015'), (4, 4, 5995, 2015, '6/29/2015'), (5, 2, 5995, 2016, '5/6/2016'),
(6, 1, 5995, 2016, '5/20/2016'), (7, 1, 5995, 2015, '2/13/2015'), (8, 1, 5595, 2015, '2/13/2015'),
(9, 3, 5595, 2015, '7/17/2015'), (10, 1, 5995, 2015, '6/29/2015')** Thanks

Comment: Hi @hanom. I ran your query for Monthly but result did not match with yours. Here the output **col label value
Rev 2/2015 1
Qty 2/2015 5995
Rev 2/2015 1
Qty 2/2015 5595
Rev 3/2015 0
Qty 3/2015 0
Rev 4/2015 0
Qty 4/2015 0
Rev 5/2015 1
Qty 5/2015 5995
Rev 6/2015 4
Qty 6/2015 5995
Rev 6/2015 1
Qty 6/2015 5995
Rev 7/2015 3
Qty 7/2015 5995
Rev 7/2015 3
Qty 7/2015 5595
Rev 8/2015 0
Qty 8/2015 0
Rev 9/2015 1
Qty 9/2015 5995**

Comment: @Allen_Delon Um... don't mind result you get is ready to use in SSRS but result I post is result inside CTE not last result.

Comment: Hi @Chanom,
I just figured it out how your code is working. Thanks for your time.